# Imprimir valor de tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, login

Tenho um sistema de login, que cada usuário é redirecionado a uma página especifica. Na minha tabela do banco de dados tenho as colunas nome, usuario, senha e nível.

Gostaria que quando o usuário logasse, aparecesse o nome cadastrado no banco de dados na sua página de boas vindas.
A parte do `echo` já ta resolvida e já está imprimido na tela, porém só consigo com a variável `usuario`, os dados da coluna `nome` não consigo imprimir na tela.

Esse é meu arquivo que faz a validação do login:

```
<?php 
require ("db.php");

$usuario = $_POST['inputUsuario'];
$senha = md5($_POST['inputPassword']);

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$dados = $query->fetch_array();

if ($row > 0){
if($dados['nivel'] == 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['inputUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['inputPassword'];
    header('Location: usuarios/usuario1.php');
}else if($dados['nivel'] == 2){
session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['inputUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['inputPassword'];
    header('Location: usuarios/usuario2.php');
}else if($dados['nivel'] == 3){
session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['inputUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['inputPassword'];
    header('Location: usuarios/usuario3.php');
}

}else{
    header('Location: index.php?msg=1');
}
?>
```

Local onde to tentando imprimir o nome:

```
        <h2><?php echo "Bem vindo ". $_SESSION['nome'];?></h2>
```

Comment: Como aparte e não diretamente focado na pergunta, considere proteger a sua página contra *mysql injection attacks*, validando os dados de entrada ou utilizando *prepared statements*. Onde está a ser feito o `echo` ? Coloque esse código também

Comment: mas aonde está o erro? não estou vendo vc passar a coluna nome em lugar algum! Se possível, posta o código da parte aonde vc está tentando imprimir os dados

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Diego, Tentei passar os dados da coluna nome usando mysqli_fetch_assoc e não deu.
Da forma que o código está, como eu poderia incluir uma váriavel para a coluna nome?

Desculpa pelas perguntas, mas esse é meu primeiro arquivo que trabalho com php e banco de dados, e praticamente não tenho experiência quase nenhuma.

Answer (score 0):

A campo `nome` em `$_SESSION` não foi atribuído na página de validação de login, logo não irá funcionar. Construa esse campo com base no que vem da tabela em `$row["nome"]`:

```
if ($row > 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['inputUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['inputPassword'];
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $dados['nome']; //assumi aqui o campo se chama nome

    if($dados['nivel'] == 1){
        header('Location: usuarios/usuario1.php');
    } else if($dados['nivel'] == 2){
        header('Location: usuarios/usuario2.php');
    } else if($dados['nivel'] == 3){
        header('Location: usuarios/usuario3.php');
    }
}
```

Repare também como ao mesmo tempo acabei por separar as instruções que eram comuns a todos os casos dos `ifs` tornando o código mais simples e organizado. Agora ficou apenas dentro do `ifs` a unica instrução que é diferente, o `header()`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67175/discussion-on-answer-by-isac-imprimir-valor-de-tabela)

Comment: @Maniero Agradeço o aviso, de facto estendeu-se bastante e até desnecessariamente.